# INT is incompatible with text

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a problem with the query I am trying to implement to my .net code

Here is the query I need to implement

```
insert into audit (username, action, editdate) 
values(@username, 
      'user=' + @user + ' deleted comboid = convert(varchar(MAX),' + @comboid + ') of '
      + @distributorname, GETDATE())
```

where `comboid` is an `int` type

The problem is the error I get:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with text

The point is that no matter how I cast or convert the expression, I always get this error.

Any idea?

Comment: You should use **proper parametrization** for your query to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities!

Comment: First thing to do: stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead, and all kinds of things will be better.

Comment: Could you add the C# code that tries to build this query? There is something not clear in your code above.

Comment: @Steve i have put the query in the Gridview Update Command

Comment: Debug hint: Assign the SQL to a variable, then look at the SQL. Fixes most of the problems people have when doing bulk string manipulation without proper debugging. If you do it like this you get a nice string you can copy/paste into SSMS and check the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that "action" value of

```
'user=' + @user + ' deleted comboid = convert(varchar(MAX),'  + @comboid + ') of ' + @distributorname
```

you have the `convert` in the wrong place. It will now be part of the resulting string.

You probably meant:

```
'user=' + @user + ' deleted comboid = ' + convert(varchar(MAX), @comboid) + ' of ' + @distributorname
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realize it

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONCAT`

```
insert into audit (username, action, editdate) 
values(
    @username, 
    CONCAT('user=', @user, ' deleted comboid = convert(varchar(MAX),', @comboid, ') of '), 
    GETDATE()
)
```

Comment: it doesn't recognize the concat function

Comment: What database you are using? I thought it's MS SQL.

Comment: `CONCAT` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** and isn't available in earlier versions .....

Comment: +1 @marc_s, cast it instead

`'user=' + @user + ' deleted comboid = ' +  CAST(@comboid AS VARCHAR(10))`